# Postgres how to pivot table

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
         date        number   value
-----------------------------------------------
    01/01/2017 4:00   287    4818007
    01/01/2017 4:00   291    4797865
    01/01/2017 5:00   287    4818007
    01/01/2017 5:00   291    4797865
    01/01/2017 6:00   287    4818007
    01/01/2017 6:00   291    4797865
```

This table is the result from a query, so the result can be different. I dont want to show the result like this table, I want this one:

```
      date              287       291
-----------------------------------------------
    01/01/2017 4:00   4797865   4818007        
    01/01/2017 5:00   4797865   4818007 
    01/01/2017 6:00   4818007   4797865
```

As I've say before, the result can be different and columns are not going to be always the same so, I can't create a pivot table with the Postgres `crosstab` function because I dont know the number of columns (numbers) that I'm going to have.

Anyone knows how to create the second table??

Comment: `crosstab` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: I cant find anything to solve my problem...

Comment: Is json output good for you?